# Image not showing in live server - Laravel 4.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Am working on laravel 4.2, I can able to show the image in localhost, but not in the live server for example the image tag,

```
<img src="images/data/d3ss.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive">
```

Works good in localhost but not in live server,

If we hit the image url in browser it says NotFoundException in live sever but in localhost I can able to see the image

```
http://xxxx.com/yyy/public/data/d3ss.jpg [NotFoundException]
http://localhost/yyy/public/data/d3ss.jpg [Working]
```

The image has been place in public/images/data

I even tried with

```
URL::to('/').'/images/data/d3ss.jpg'
```

works in localhost not in server

Please guide me, how to solve this issue.

Am sorry,

I Just found the solution. 
Actually I have mistakenly start the image file name with numbers like 8989_filename.jpg. When I remove the numbers at front it works in server. But even in localhost with numbers like 8989_filename.jpg is working.

Any other suggestions? 
Thanks for advice.

Comment: `asset('images/data/d3ss.jpg')`

Comment: I tried. But not working

Comment: Did you ever figure out what was causing this? I just switched to live server and I am having the same problem....

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the `HTML::image` helper.

Example

`{{ HTML::image('img/picture.jpg', 'a picture', array('class' => 'my-class')) }}`

More info [here](http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/185/generating-an-html-image-element)

Answer (score 0):

I think, you need to set correct rights to your image directory on the server.

```
sudo chmod -R 770 /var/www/your-site-path/public/data/
sudo chown -R username:www-data /var/www/your-site-path/public/data/
```

Comment: Am sorry, I tried by changing the permission. Still not getting the image.